# Fix error trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I've searched for other questions but couldn't find an answer. I get the following error.

> Trying to get property 'nameP' of non-object

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $hourID = $request->hour_id;
    $id = (Hour::latest()->first()->id) + 1;
    $projectID = $request->project_id;

    $sub = DB::table('hours')->join('projects',
        function ($join) use ($projectID, $id) {
            $join->on('hours.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
                ->where('hours.project_id', '=', $projectID)
                ->where('hours.id', '=', $id);
        })->select('nameP')
        ->get()->first();

    $name = $sub->nameP;
    $hour = Hour::create([
        'id' => $hourID,
        'project_id' => $request->project_id,
        'day' => $request->day,
        'nHours' => $request->nHours,
        'notesH' => $request->notesH
    ]);

    return Response::json([$hour, 'nameP' => $name]);
}
```

If I execute this code using Laravel Tinker it works so I don't understand why this error occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: what gives you dd($sub);?

Comment: The correct object, exactely like I run in artisan tinker

Comment: you are using ->get()->first();. Change it or to get(); or to first(); and then ->first(); will give you object and  ->get(); probably collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting multiple records if you use `get()` method.

using `first()` you'll get only one collection.

Remove `get()`, and use only `first()` method

```
$name = '';
$sub = DB::table('hours')->join('projects', function($join) use ($projectID,$id){
                                $join->on('hours.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
                                ->where('hours.project_id', '=', $projectID)
                                ->where('hours.id', '=', $id);
                            })->select('nameP')->first();
if(!empty($sub)){
    $name=$sub->nameP;
}
```

Comment: Consider it as true, Glad to help Happy coding, :0